# Best way to pass data in between classes and forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is some background information on the project I am working on:

I am creating a spectral collection service MDI application that is used to collect spectral information.  Inside my main form I have a hardware control class that orchestrates and controls a PLC control class and a spectral collection class.  Inside the spectral collection and plc class are threads that run and continuously collect information about the spectrometer and plc respectively.

In addition, I am making the application so that a user can open a new child form and view all information about the system.  I am trying to figure out a way for this system information to be seen from the child forms as they are continuously being updated.

I am having some ideas of using threads, timers, and/or events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is by far the easiest way to pass information between classes.

```
#region Variables

private static bool bTest = false;

#endregion

#region Functions

public static bool getbTest()
{
    return bTest;
}

public static void setbTest(bool b)
{
    bTest = b;
}

#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Progress` class to update the UI based on the progress of some background operation.  The UI can create the object, defining how it plans to update the UI using the data, and then pass it to the non-UI operation which can provide the data without needing to know how the UI will be updated.

Here is a comparable implementation that you can use if you are using an earlier version of .NET:

```
public interface IProgress<T>
{
    void Report(T data);
}

public class Progress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    SynchronizationContext context;
    public Progress()
    {
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current
            ?? new SynchronizationContext();
    }

    public Progress(Action<T> action)
        : this()
    {
        ProgressReported += action;
    }

    public event Action<T> ProgressReported;

    void IProgress<T>.Report(T data)
    {
        var action = ProgressReported;
        if (action != null)
        {
            context.Post(arg => action((T)arg), data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something to note about `Progress` - it uses `SynchronizationContext.Post` in its `OnReport` method which means it will not update the UI if the heavy work is done on the UI thread. So threads/tasks are needed in order for it to work properly.

Comment: @Default It is *designed* to be used from a non-UI thread, it is well documented as saying so.  The OP also specifically said he's using it from a non-UI thread.

Comment: The information is retrieved and updated from the spectrometer very fast and continuously.  I also don't want the UI in the child forms to be updated that fast and with repeat information and not that often because it will make it GUI sluggish.

Comment: @Berigan Then either don't report progress every single time you have progress to update, or have the code handling the progress updated event not do anything in the handler if you don't need to update progress.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  I am fairly new to C# and designing software.

Comment: @Berigan If you don't want to report progress every single time you have new data, then *don't report progress every single time you have new data*.  Determine your own metrics for when you want to update the UI with new data.  I can't know what you want them to be.  When you've come up with some criteria, write code to determine if that criteria is met.

Comment: @Servy If I am not mistaken, the Progress class is only available in .NET 4.5.  I am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: I am unsure how to use this.  Can you explain to me what this is and how to use it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If your constrained to using WinForms I recommend using the [Smart Client Software Factory](http://smartclient.codeplex.com/), or better yet use WPF and use [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).

Both have the concept of sharing components around.